# How to run SENTINEL slaves command using go-redis?

Tags: redis

I set up Redis client as follow:

```
redisClient := redisclient.NewClient(&redisclient.Options{
    Addr:    <sentinel-pod-IP>:<sentinel-pod-port>,
    Password: "",
    DB:       0,
})
```

I ran `SENTINEL slaves <master-name>` command via:

```
import redisclient "github.com/go-redis/redis"

......

cmd := redisclient.NewStringSliceCmd("SENTINEL", "slaves", "master-name") 
redisClient.Process(cmd)
slaveInfos, err := cmd.Result()
```

However, I got an error running `redis: can't parse string reply: \"*40\"`.

`SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name <master-name>` works for same client setup.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and found the solution on github:
https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/788

You need to use `NewSliceCmd`, e.g.

```
        cmd := redis.NewSliceCmd("sentinel", "slaves", "clusterName-master")
        client.Process(cmd)
        _, err := cmd.Result()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Unable to issue `sentinel slaves %s-master ` cmd on (%s): %s", clusterName, err.Error())
        }
```